# SQL query taking long to execute SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I suspect that the below query is bottlenecking the server but I am unsure how to tune the query to make it more efficient. If you have any suggestions please let me know. I know case statements are fine for querying as well as using left join instead of union. So I think the problem must be in the other statements in the where statement. But as I said I am unsure.

```
SELECT
svc.[Name] AS 'Type',
os.OrderID,
os.CustomerID,
os.Transit,
os.ApplicantFullName,
os.OriginalTransit,
ISNULL(p.UnitNumber , '') + ' ' + ISNULL(p.StreetNumber, '') AS 'Number', ISNULL(st.[Name], 'NULL') AS 'Street',
c.[Name] AS 'City',
p.PostalCode,
os.RequesterRefNo,
os.MortgagePurpose,
os.GrossTAT
os.NetTAT
os.StopTime
os.ModifiedGrossTAT,
os.ReOpenFlag,
os.MinReOpenDate,
O.NegotiatedFees,
O.BranchLogonID,
CASE
When os.Transit in ('710','740','745','750','760','770','820','830','850','871','7409','7709') THEN 'Calgary 1' When os.Transit in ('720','730','774','780','783','790','821','834','840','858','881','894') THEN 'Calgary 2' When os.Transit in ('744','763','810','7639')THEN 'Calgary 3'
When os.Transit in ('736','768','779','826','837','857','876','879','887','898','899')THEN 'North 2'
When os.Transit in ('716','726','737','738','746','767','778','798','818','838','846','878')THEN 'North 3' When os.Transit in ('180')THEN 'MDO Tr 180 Edmonton'
When os.Transit in ('460','02099','New','PRIMARY')THEN 'MDO TR 460 Calgary'
END AS 'ATBRegion1',
CASE
When os.Transit in
When os.Transit in
When os.Transit in
When os.Transit in
When os.Transit in
When os.Transit in
('710','740','745','750','760','770','820','830','850','871','7409', ,'858','881','894','744','763','810','7639') THEN 'Calgary' ('728','731','735','751','755','771','775','791','795','824','835','854','855','875','885','748','844','847','888')THEN 'Edmonton' ('722','733','734','742','782','793','812','822','842','853','893')THEN 'South' ('724','753','772','773','832','836','866','867','877','896','712','781','873')THEN 'Central' ('719','729','739','749','759','769','789','799','819','829','737','738','746','767','778','798','818','838','846','878')THEN 'North' ('180','460','02099','New','PRIMARY')THEN 'MDO/Consumer Credit'
END AS 'ATBRegion2',
CASE
WHEN os.CustomerID
WHEN os.CustomerID
WHEN os.CustomerID
WHEN os.CustomerID
WHEN os.CustomerID
WHEN os.CustomerID
WHEN os.CustomerID
ELSE os.CustomerID
like '%ATB%' THEN 'ATB'
like '%PROS%' THEN 'PROSPERA'
like '%BLC%' THEN 'BLC'
like 'BW%' THEN 'BWorx'
like 'CIBC%' THEN 'CIBC'
like '%PROS%' THEN 'PROSPERA'
like 'FNF%' THEN 'CIBC'
END AS CLIENTIDCLEAN,
CASE
WHEN os.Cancelled =
0x1 THEN 'Cancelled'
      ELSE ''
END AS 'Cancelled',
os.AppraiserFirm,
CASE
WHEN ai.AppraiserTypeID = 1 THEN 'SS' WHEN ai.AppraiserTypeID = 2 THEN 'SA' WHEN ai.AppraiserTypeID = 3 THEN 'UC' WHEN ai.AppraiserTypeID = 4 THEN 'NC' WHEN ai.AppraiserTypeID = 5 THEN 'UCFF'
FROM
END AS 'AppraiserType',
CASE
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',ADE.[ESTIMATED_MARKET_VALUE.1]) = 0 THEN Substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(ADE.[ESTIMATED_MARKET_VALUE.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$',''), 1, CHARINDEX('.',
REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(ADE.[ESTIMATED_MARKET_VALUE.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$',''), 1)) ELSE
Substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(ADE.[ESTIMATED_MARKET_VALUE.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$',''), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(ADE.[ESTIMATED_MARKET_VALUE.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$',''), 1))
END as 'AppraisedValue',
REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(ADE.[ESTIMATED_MARKET_VALUE.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$','') as AppValue, REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([EST_MARKET_VALUE_RANGE_FROM.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$','') as AppValueRangeFrom, REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST([EST_MARKET_VALUE_RANGE_TO.1] as NVarchar(4000)),',',''),'$','') as AppValueRangeTo, NULLIF(os.MarketValue,0) AS 'EstimatedMarketValue',
CASE WHEN UC.Cityid is null THEN 'Rural' ELSE 'Urban' END as Region,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(p.postalcode, 2, 1) = '0' then 'Rural' ELSE 'Urban' END as PostalRural, EL.TTLORIGINVOICEAMOUNT as Price,
EL.TTLVENDORCOST as Cost,
os.AppraiserGrossTAT,
os.AppraiserNetTAT,
EXID.expid as EXCEPTIONID,
SD.PROPERTYVALUE as 'CleanAppraisedValue',
r.FirstName + ' ' + r.LastName AS "Requester Name"
DataMart.dbo.OrderSummary AS os
left JOIN
CAPS.dbo.[order] AS o on os.orderid = o.orderid Left Join
CAPS.dbo.[Requester] as r on o.RequesterID = r.RequesterID left JOIN
CAPS.dbo.Service AS svc ON(svc.ServiceID = os.ServiceID) left JOIN
CAPS.dbo.OrderStatus AS ostat ON(ostat.OrderStatusID = o.OrderStatusID) left JOIN
CAPS.dbo.Property AS p ON(p.PropertyID = os.PropertyID) left JOIN
CAPS.dbo.AppraiserInfo AS ai ON (ai.gp_vendorID = os.AppraiserFirm) LEFT JOIN
CAPS.dbo.Province AS prov ON(prov.ProvinceID = p.ProvinceID) LEFT JOIN
CAPS.dbo.City AS c ON(c.CityID = p.CityID) LEFT JOIN
CAPS.dbo.Street AS st ON(st.StreetID = p.StreetID) LEFT JOIN
Caps.cruser.UrbanCity UC ON C.Cityid = UC.Cityid LEFT JOIN
fbc.dbo.TGO_EXTENDEDORDERS_LINE EL WITH (NOLOCK) ON O.Orderid = EL.Ordernumber LEFT JOIN
(select [ORDERNUMBER], MAX(expID) as expid from (SELECT
[ORDERNUMBER] ,isnull([EXCEPTIONID],0) as expID
FROM [FBC].[dbo].[TGO_EXTENDEDORDERSERVICES]) dd group by dd.[ORDERNUMBER]) EXID on EXID.ORDERNUMBER = os.orderid
LEFT JOIN (select ORDERID, max(PROPERTYVALUE) as PROPERTYVALUE from TrendPoint.dbo.SourceData where DATAID = 0 and CLEANDATA_FLAG in (0,1)group by orderID having
COUNT(*) < 3) SD on SD.ORDERID = os.OrderID
LEFT JOIN (select * from CAPS.dbo.AppraisalDataExtract where WorkingCopy = 0)ADE on ADE.OrderID = os.OrderID
WHERE os.CompletionDate >= '2012-01-01' and os.OrderID in (2427915, 2427917,2437863,2437880,2437630)
```

Comment: Can you please post the explain plan of the query, the indexes of the tables that you're using, the selectivity of the columns you're filtering on, and the number of rows as an absolute minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to open execution plan for this query to find the most expensive Operators and start from there if there is no other process blocking this query. 
maybe Missing index and too many joins

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to speed up your web application is to enable query caching in your database, which caches commonly used SQL queries in memory for virtually instant access by the next page that makes the same request.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/speed-up-your-web-site-with-mysql-query-caching/

Answer (score 0):

One area you may want to consider using more predicates in your ON statement. This would enable your query to eliminate rows even before executing your final WHERE filter and this could create a situation of allowing better use of indexes.

Another area that you may want to look at is the use of like%% often times like does not allow this use of indexes when not having the search characters at the beginning of the literal..i.e like 'BW%' will use an index but like'%BW' will not use an index.

Your best bet though is took have a look at your query execution plan(and possibly submit that here. Query analyzer is really is going to be your best source in solving your problem.